# Python Keras - compatibility between Windows and Linux

Tags: python, keras

I have trained and saved a Keras model in Windows 10, Python 3.5, Keras 2.0.6.

In Windows I can then load the model and reuse it. But, when I try and load the model in Linux (Ubuntu), Keras 2.0.5, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Optimizer weight shape (90,) not compatible with provided weight shape (31, 90)

I have tried uninstalling Keras and reinstalling using Pip and then doing the same with Conda. Is this a compatibility issue with Windows and Linux, or something else?

Many thanks

Code to train and save the model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

import keras.backend as K
def inRange(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.cast(K.less_equal(K.abs(y_true-y_pred), 8), "int32")) / K.shape(y_true)[0]

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n1, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))


# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', inRange])

# Fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=maxEpoch, batch_size=10)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# save the model
model.save('length_predict.h5', overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True)
```

Code to load the saved model:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import load_model

# Custom metric for use in the keras ANN models, needs to be loaded as a custom object
def inRange(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    Function for determining the percentage of points that fall within the +-8% error
    '''
    return K.sum(K.cast(K.less_equal(K.abs(y_true-y_pred), 8), "int32")) / K.shape(y_true)[0]

# Load the ANN
model_length = load_model('length_predict.h5', custom_objects={'inRange':inRange})
```

Comment: please provide some code of your model

Comment: @Paddy I've added some code snippets. Thanks

Comment: Recommend to double check the keras version on Windows/Linux. Need to be exactly same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, it was in fact a version incompatibility issue.

For some reason Anaconda installs version 2.0.6 in Windows, but only 2.0.5 in Linux. I manually downloaded and installed 2.0.6 (from the Keras github page) on my Linux machine and the code then worked :)